# В зависимости от ip швырять на разные версии сайта

Tags: php

Написал следующее:

```
class GetUserLocation {
    function GetUserRealIp()
        {
            if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) 
            {
                $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
            }
            elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
            {
                $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
            }
            else
            {
                $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
            }
        return $ip;
        }
    function WhereUser($page)
        {
            $wherexmlip = "http://ipgeobase.ru:7020/geo?ip=".$ip;
            $xml_str = file_get_contents($wherexmlip);
            $xml = new SimplexmlElement($xml_str);
            foreach($xml->ip as $new) {
                $location= $new->country;
            }
            session_start();
            if (empty($_SESSION['location'])){
                    $_SESSION['location'] = $location;
                if ($location !== 'RU'){
                LocalRedirect('/en/'.$page);
                }else{
                LocalRedirect('/'.$page);               
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Но в итоге у меня получается бесконечный цикл. Где ошибся?

Comment: Откуда берется переменная $ip в методе класса WhereUser? Мб так правильнее function WhereUser($page, $ip)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Или так:

```
$wherexmlip = "http://ipgeobase.ru:7020/geo?ip=".self::GetUserRealIp();
```